# Shared variables in multithreaded programs

Tags: multithreading

As far as I know, in multithreaded applications each thread has its own individual stack and shares the heap with others. So, I was wondering if this is a language-, compiler- or OS-depenadent feature? Are all multithreaded applications like this?

My second question is if there is a shared variable among threads, is it created in heap or not? Is there any other possible way to share a variable among the threads except through heap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is an OS-dependent feature but all OSes agree on the same basic principle of having a common heap space and separate stacks

Shared variables are stored in the heap memory. Threads share variables using the heap only.. obviously that's not the only way to share **data**, there are signals, callbacks and many other techniques...

Comment: So, it means that if I define a shared variable in an openmp pragma, it is translated to a malloc()??

Comment: No, it means that there is only 1 heap per process and each thread running under such process has its own stack memory (relative to the current execution path). Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 2):

Each thread will get its own stack memory that is feature of OS.
All multi-threaded applications likes and follows same feature.

> My second question is if there is a shared variable among threads, is
>   it created in heap or not? Is there any other possible way to share a
>   variable among the threads except through heap?

According to Java there is no other way to share variable but through heap.

Comment: I doubt the Java doc states it like this. The memory is not just divided between the stack(s) and the heap(s). Think about a static and shared variable, would you say it's allocated on the JIT's heap (provided it is different from the runtime's heap(s))? Would you say a file's buffer, allocated by the kernel, lives on the kernel's heap?

Answer (score 2):

I would also say the stack is OS-dependent

However the heap (not the unified memory abstraction) is language-dependent as some languages maintain one heap per thread. This does not mean that the data allocated on this heap cannot be seen by other threads, though. It's just that a language does not have to use a shared concurrent data structure for allocations or a shared pages pool, which would be pretty stupid on a computing cluster for example.

Now there are also languages that enforce the isolation of some memory addresses (and maybe memory pages although it would be for performances rather than consistency), but this is yet another matter not related to allocations themselves.